# null is not an object (evaluating 'str.split') React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, jsx

I keep getting the error **"null is not an object (evaluating 'str.split')"** when registering a user on my app. Once registered the user lands on the HomeScreen which has the 'str.split' string which splits the firebase Displayname into the first word (first name). cant work out how to fix the error.

```
import { View, Text, Image, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    var str = auth?.currentUser?.displayName;
    const welcomeText = (str.split(' ')[0]);
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
                <View style={styles.overviewContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.welcomeContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Hello <Text style={styles.welcomeTextBold}>{welcomeText}</Text></Text>
                        <Image style={styles.welcomeIcon} source={require('../assets/images/Welcome-Icon.png')} />
                    </View> 
                </View>
        </View>
```

Comment: The error is that `str` is null. So either `auth`, `auth.currentUser`, or `auth.currentUser.displayName` aren't set.

Comment: `console.log` the str and check if it's a valid `string`

Comment: @Rohit its a valid string, it works perfectly, it splits the displayName but I am still getting the error

Comment: Are you sure it's a perfect string even for newly sign up users? By default displayName is null.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change below line

```
const welcomeText = (str.split(' ')[0]);
```

with

```
const welcomeText = (str?.split(' ')[0]) || '';
```